# Поск ячейки в Excel с определенным значением Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Деканат факультета каждую неделю выкладывает xlsx файл с расписанием занятий для каждой группы.

Хочу написать программу, которая по запросу будет выдавать расписание на выбраный день для выбраной группы.

Проблема в том, что форматируют они расписание не совсем статично, так, для одного курса ячейки заполняются начиная с D2, для другого с D7. Статически забивать в программу местоположение ячеек с нужными данными как-то не очень хорошая идея. Пришел к решению о переборе ячеек в диапазоне A1:D7 для определения группы, к которой нужно расписание, на наличие ключевой записи,
и перебор на поиск дня недели. От нее уже можно все просчитать и узнать расположение лекций.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
**
for row in range(1,8):
for cell in range (1,15):
    a1= sheet.cell(row=rw, column=col).value
    if (a1==str(group)):
        startrowgroup=rw
        startcolgroup=col
        col=col+1
        break
rw=rw+1 
**
```

(идея в том, чтобы в буф переменных сохранить положение первой записи и уже от этого плясать с выводами данных).

Проблема в том, что при доходе до a1= sheet.cell(row=rw, column=col).value
a1 не получает значение ячейки. ( если дописать вывод значения, то будет None)

Comment: вы можете выложить куда-нибудь пример excel файла?

Comment: Ну так пропустите его и берите следущее (плюс лимит на число пропусков)

Comment: https://fex.net/#!010826555166

Comment: с таким форматированием - это та еще задача...

Comment: действительную проблему стоит в заголовке указать ("не получает значение"). Чтобы понять в чём проблема, создайте искусственный  пример excel файла, и полный, но минимальный пример кода, который из него A1 ячейку пытается прочитать. [mcve]

Comment: Вылаживает. OMG.